# Ich bins Michel or Ich bin Zmichel or what?

Tags: oral-communication

From the start of [this short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tVMeh7RAOA) the boy introduces himself as (from what I am hearing)

> Hi, ich bins Michel

or

> Hi, ich bin Zmichel

Neither of which makes sense to me. What is he saying?

Comment: "ich bin's, Michel" (bin's= bin es)?

Comment: The second kid on the other hand just says "Ich bin Sven" so can see how this is confusing :)... "Ich bin's, Michel" "Ich bin Sven."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The little boy definitely says

> Hi, ich bin's, Michel.

Like already said in the comments, "ich bin's" means "ich bin es".

If it helps you to understand the meaning, it is the same as the famous ["It's me, Mario"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhadLMDWcGA) from the character in the Super Mario games.